# jquery mobile swipe stops if i swipe right on the first page and and left on the last page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 4 pages and I can swipe between them smoothly. But when I swipe right on the first which doesn't have a page before that or on the last page which doesn't have a page after that, then my swipe stops. It doesn't event go to the next or previous page anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2 
/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
HOME
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="about">
ABOUT
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="portfolio">
PORTFOLIO
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="contact">
CONTACT
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-
1.3.2.min.js">
</script>
 <script>

        $(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
        var nextPage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]');
        if (nextPage) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextPage, {
                transition: "slide"
            });
        }
    }
    if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
        var prevPage = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
        if (prevPage) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevPage, {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
        }
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1sphmy1j/1/

Comment: instead of if (nextPage){... try if (nextPage.length > 0){...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your vars prevPage and nextPage aren't **undefined**

You may either check some page property like in

```
if (prevPage.html() !== undefined)
```

or add custom attributes like "data-first" and "data-last" to your first and last page and check them in your code like in

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-first="true">
    ....
<div data-role="page" id="contact" data-last="true">

var ap = $("body").pagecontainer("getActivePage");
if (ap.attr("data-first") !== "true") ...
if (ap.attr("data-last") !== "true") ...
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/e578z2re/)